# Words with particular first and last letter from a list of words in an array(node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Ok, so I am confused. I have a particular txt file, and it has a lot of words in it, and i have sorted its text into an array(i think).

```
var fs = require('fs');
var words = fs.readFileSync("words.txt").toString();
words = words.split('\n');

var starting = ("(somerandomletter)");
var ending = ("(anotherrandomletter)");
```

So the variables starting and ending are any random English letter. Now what i want to do is to find the words from the text file, and check if a word has the first and last letter, given in the starting and ending variable, and then print thise words in the console. I am quite a beginner at this, so i am confused.

Comment: JS `String` has `startsWith()` and `endsWith()` methods.

Comment: Here's a hint, because what it seems like you're asking is for us to tell you how to write your software, take a look at string splitting. Right now you're storing all of the words from the txt file as a single string, so you could split you're string at spaces (assuming that's what is seperating different words), then using the methods the comment above suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var words = fs.readFileSync("words.txt").toString();
words = words.split('\n');

words = ["adolf", "donald", "kim"]

var starting = "d";
var ending = "d";

words.forEach(word => {
    if (word.startsWith(starting) && word.endsWith(ending))
        console.log(word)
})
```